# Пальто во множественном числе

Tags: выбор-слов, множественное-число

Узнал, что слово "пальто" одинаково звучит как в ед. ч., так и во мн. ч. Значит предложение ниже будет корректным и в письменной, и в устной речи? Для всех остальных подобных слов это тоже верно? Где можно найти список этих слов?

> У меня есть много пальто.

Звучит странно.

Comment: Интересно, а как по-другому, чтобы не странно?

Comment: @Ларf, плащи :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**пальто́**
Существительное, неодушевлённое, средний род, несклоняемое.
(***Тип склонения 0*** по классификации А. А. Зализняка; *нулевое склонение* подразумевает, что существительное остается неизменным в любом падеже и числе.)

Определить падеж *пальто* можно только в словосочетаниях, по согласуемому слову:
в красное пальто — ед.ч., В.п.;
в красном пальто — ед.ч., П.п.;
красными пальто — мн.ч., Т.п.

Есть такой школьный стишок, который показывает возможность определения падежа у несклоняемых существительных [(у кого?) — у кенгуру — Р.п., (кто?) — кенгуру — И.п.]:
*Морж спросил у Кенгуру:

— Как выносишь ты жару?

— Я от холода дрожу! —

Кенгуру сказал Моржу.*
(Б.Заходер)

Есть достаточное количество слов(обычно, они иностранного происхождения), которые входят в группу исключений из правил русского языка и при склонении по падежам не изменяют свое окончание:
*шоссе, метро, какао, авеню, жабо, медресе, инкогнито, кураре, пюре, монпансье, банджо...*

Их можно найти в ***Современном словаре несклоняемых слов русского языка*** (около 3000 слов), И.Д.Успенская, АСТ, 2009.

Некоторые из них можно посмотреть здесь:
[**Род несклоняемых существительных**](http://lik-bez.com/board/morfologija/sushhestvitelnoe/rod_nesklonjaemykh_sushhestvitelnykh/31-1-0-399).